# How to use styles for 2 spannable string?

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

I create a variable where add 2 lines using `SpannableStringBuilder`.
After i use span for each of string.
But unfortunately the style applied not correctly.
Something wrong with my positions, i need to use red color only for `item.statusDecription`(ex: 26 Jun 2020, 12:54)
What might be the problem?

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(listItemView.context, R.font.roboto_bold)
val consentDescription = SpannableStringBuilder(item.consentDescription)
val statusDescription = SpannableStringBuilder(item.statusDescription)
val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder("$consentDescription $statusDescription")
spannable.apply {
    setSpan(StyleSpan(typeface!!.style), 0, item.consentDescription.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                listItemView.context,
                R.color.grey_100
            )
        ), 0, item.consentDescription.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    )
    setSpan(StyleSpan(typeface.style), item.statusDescription.indexOf(item.statusDescription, 0), item.statusDescription.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                listItemView.context,
                R.color.red
            )
        ), item.statusDescription.indexOf(item.statusDescription, 0), item.statusDescription.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    )
}
subTitleView.text = spannable
```

[image]

Comment: Hi can you try by setting only one? just to verify `subTitleView.text = consentDescription`

Comment: @ShaluTD updated question. Proble with positions.

Comment: whats the required screenshot

Comment: I think you can try to debug to find out what number is in here: item.statusDescription.length and why it is less then you need.

Comment: Is this  `26 Jun 2020, 12:54` value of item.statusDecription ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
    val description ="Sprint Bank Example"
    val status ="5 26 Jun 2020, 12:54"
    val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.calibri)

    val spannableDescription = SpannableString(description)
    val spannableStatus = SpannableString(status)

    val spannableBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder().apply {
        spannableDescription.setSpan(
            ForegroundColorSpan(context.getColorCompat(R.color.gray10)), 0, spannableDescription.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        spannableDescription.setSpan(typeface, 0, description.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        append(spannableDescription)

        spannableStatus.setSpan(
            ForegroundColorSpan(context.getColorCompat(R.color.red)), 0, spannableStatus.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        spannableStatus.setSpan(typeface, 0, status.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        append("\n")
        append(spannableStatus)
    }

    subTitleView.text  = spannableBuilder
```

**Output**:

[image]